# Were "Baadshah" and "Phir Bhi Dil Hai Hindustani" well received upon release?

Tags: reception, indian-cinema, baadshah

Were the movies "[Baadshah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baadshah_%281999_film%29#Reception)" and "[Phir Bhi Dil Hai Hindustani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phir_Bhi_Dil_Hai_Hindustani)" well received upon release? I have heard that both of these movies were flops, however many people love both of these movies.

Were these movies successful movies?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed?

Comment: The question is closed because any posts here would most likely be opinion based. The person asking the question could easily Google for reviews and news on how much money either movie made to gain the answer for themselves.

Comment: Related meta discussion http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/is-this-question-primarily-opinion-based

Comment: @MattD opinion based, how? It's answer going to be fact based not opinion based.

Comment: Again, you can easily search for how much each movie made and infer for yourself whether or not these movies were commercially successful. Further, outside of simply doing the research to provide the numbers, the resulting, "Yes it was," or, "No it was not," response WOULD be opinion based. Overall, the problem is that you could easily find this information for yourself and derive your own conclusion(s).

Comment: @MattD most of the question present here can be answered by Google/Wikipedia itself, so are we going to close them too? Second a movie is hit or not can't be opinion based, it is decided by collection not opinion.

Comment: @MattD interesting read for you on simple question (answerable easily from Google or Wikipedia) http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: Except you show little to no effort to have done any research on your own. Seriously, looking up how much a movie makes is one of the easiest things to do, as well as reviews to gauge how well it was received. Another characteristic emphasized on this site is that you put forth some of your own effort before asking a question. It would seem to me you did none of that. I stand by my reasoning, so I'm not going to debate this any further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The movie Baadshah was not really what you would call a "flop" - the [movie opened very well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baadshah_%281999_film%29#Reception), netting US$2.6 million but went on to gross US$4.6 million. This makes it the [#6 movie of 1999](http://www.boxofficeindia.com/showProd.php?itemCat=205&catName=MTk5OQ==) in the Indian Box Office.

These numbers are, however, below average in the world wide market in comparison to many of the other movies released in 1999.

Phir Bhi Dil Hai Hindustani, on the other hand, [was declared a flop by the Indian Box Office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phir_Bhi_Dil_Hai_Hindustani), and it went on to [rank #16 in the Indian Box Office for 2000](http://www.boxofficeindia.com/showProd.php?itemCat=206&catName=MjAwMA==).